# Decrypt failed with error 0X90317 Underlying connection was closed

Tags: c#, wcf, https

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtYFm.gif)

When WCF connect to ThirdPart ,elapsed more than 15 seconds ,then got an error

> The underlying connection was closed:The connection was closed
>   unexpectedly

Network tracing like this

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmH99.jpg)

I guess the ThirdPart change the secret when 15s.

What's the truth?

Comment: Have you contacted the owners of the third party web service?  They're the ones best positioned to answer your question.

Comment: I have the same issue - although it's only happening when I am receiving larger blocks of data from a POST. Looking at my VS trace, the difference between a successful receive and a failed one is that I see thread(s) exit before the receive.

Comment: To add to my previous comment: It turned out that the underlying issue for me was that the TLS version supported at the client end was not supported at the server end. 

I ended up putting in a web proxy to "downgrade" the encryption since I was not able to upgrade the server end. Once I had done this, my POST operations were successful. This allowed my code to function properly until the server could be upgraded.